# Search Console Crawl Error with no Response code

Tags: google-search-console, redirects

When Google crawls my clients site it throws out a list of URLs as errors but there is no response code.

When following the URL link in Search Console it will 302 redirect me to a legit URL within my clients website.

There is a good amount of content on the page as well.

The explanation from Search Console is:

> The target URL doesn't exist, but your server is not returning a 404
>   (file not found) error.

What reasons could the page be classed as 'not found' but when clicking on the link it redirects correctly.

Comment: Probably just another Googlism.

Comment: Please try the "Fetch as Google" feature on one of these URLs and report any additional information that it provides.

Comment: Does Google use the term "soft 404" for these URLs?    You say that they redirect.  Google treats URLs that redirect to a central page (such as the home page) the same as URLs that are 404.  Google calls such cases "soft 404".

Comment: Thank you Stephen Ostermiller,
Google does use the term soft 404, the pages do redirect to a main page as well.